# For raster calculation using gdal, what is the importance of raster band in input dataset?

Tags: python, gis, raster, gdal, qgis

I have 5 .tif files and I want to do some arithmetic operation using raster calculation. I see the number of different solution.

Solution number on. 1:  [raster calculation using band 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216851/python-script-for-raster-calculation-using-gdal)

second solution using 2 bands: [raster calculation using 2 band](http://geoexamples.blogspot.com/2012/12/raster-calculations-with-gdal-and-numpy.html)

My question: what difference does the **raster band**(either 1 or multiple) make while doing raster operation like

(11*input1+ 22*input2+ 33*input3+ 44* input4+ 55* input5)-33442

What things should we consider before doing such operation regarding input(raster data) band?

I have 2 set of input .tif file.

1. set1(5 .tif file with 1 raster band value(e.g. band 1))
2. set2 (5 .tif file with 2 raster bands value(e.g.band 1 and band 2))

What is the appropriate way to apply the raster calculation operation regarding band value?

If anyone who is working in GIS (gdal, or similar tools) have any idea, please share the light in this band related question. I have recently started playing around with GIS, and this is making a lot of confusion.

**.tif file having 1 band only**:

[image: example1 .tif file having 1 band only]

**.tif file having 2 band values**:

[image: example2 .tif file having 2 band values]

Comment: What bands do your rasters have? For photographic images the bands are usually red, green, and blue. But lots of other combinations exist, including non-visible frequencies. For example, [LANDSAT rasters have 11 bands](https://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/landsat-8/landsat-8-bands/), which can be combined in various interesting ways.

Comment: I think your actual question here, about the correct way to combine the bands, is actually a scientific question and not a programming one. The question is not answerable in the abstract. What are your rasters, what bands do they have, and what is your calculation intending to compute?

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks daniel for your answer, I currently have 2 set with 5 input raster file(.tif file for combination) taken in different visible range(blue, red, green ,red edge, nir). One data set has just one band and another data set with 2 bands. I have added two pictures to myquestion(inspection of property of the file using qgis).
I want to perform raster calculation in these data(5 tif file and get 1 output .tif). I guess it means getting the data in array format and performing logical operation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have any documentation about what the two bands in the mosaic file are? You can think of each band as being an independent matrix of values, just with each pixel aligned to the pixels in the other bands. It's possible that bands one and two in your mosaic file may be the same data, just with different scaling factors. Some GeoTIFF files have embedded metadata that describes each band, although I can't tell whether these files do.

Comment: @DanielPryden I think the 2 band data is the same with scaling factor different. I am given to compute the raster calculation. I currently do not have any documentation of the bands. What does it mean when we have 2 band, does it mean after raster calculation we will have 2 output.tif file or we can have 1 tif file with raster calculation from both bands data? Does it depends on equation or band value(assuming separate process for each band) for output calibration?

Answer (score 0):

Since the raster files has two band in one and one band in another. For two band we get the two raster array data and output will also be 2 and for one band output will be one based on the equation.